# How to view products from a json on fastapi

Tags: python, html, vue.js, jinja2, fastapi

I'm trying to do a digital store. I've got the products on Fastapi, and now I have to render them to the web page. I can't get how to do it. I tried importing them with VueJS, like this:

```
import productlist from ('127.0.0.1:8000/products')
        var prod = new Vue({
            $el: '#app',
            data: {
                loading: true,
                errored: false
            },
            mounted() {
                axios
                    .get('127.0.0.1:8000/products')
                    .then (response => (this.$el.info = response))
                    .catch (error => console.log(error))
                },
            methods: {
                reply_click(e) {
                    var id = event.target.getAttribute('data-id');
                    alert(id);
                }
            }
        });
```

But they don't appear on the divs they should, which is done like this:

```
<div id="app">
            <div class="row">
                <div v-for="prod in productlist" data-id="prod.id" :key="prod.id" class="col-3 producte" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal1" on-click="reply_click($event)">
                    <template>
                        <div class="producte">
                            <div class="imgdesc">
                                <img :src="prod.urlimg" class="img-fluid"><br>
                                {{ product.desc }}
                            </div>
                            <img v-if="prod.cartell === 'new'" src="imgs/sign_new_offer.png" class="cartell">
                            <img v-if="prod.cartell === 'offer'" src="imgs/sign_offer.png" class="cartell">
                        </div>
                    </template>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

And this is the JSON I have. I posted it on fastapi and I have to get it from there, not from the file I posted.

```
{
        "id": 1,
        "desc": "Kaweco sport capeless roller pen and pencil set in pouch white",
        "urlimg": "imgs/offer1.png",
        "preu": 22,
        "oferta": "no"
    },

    {
        "id": 2,
        "desc": "Hacoa masking tape holder",
        "urlimg": "imgs/offer2.png",
        "preu": 24,
        "oferta": "new"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "desc": "Hacoa black walnut business card holder",
        "urlimg": "imgs/offer3.png",
        "preu": 30,
        "oferta": "new"
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "desc": "Postalco legal envelope navy",
        "urlimg": "imgs/offer4.png",
        "preu": 15,
        "oferta": "offer"
    }
```

Okay, this is a template with the data of the first object on the json. The price ("preu") isn't in there because it goes in a modal that opens when the image is clicked.

```
<div id="app">
            <div class="row">
                <div data-id="1" :key="1" class="col-3 producte" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal1" on-click="reply_click($event)">
                    <template>
                        <div class="producte">
                            <div class="imgdesc">
                                <img :src="imgs/offer1.png" class="img-fluid"><br>
                                Kaweco sport capeless roller pen and pencil set in pouch white
                            </div>
                            <!-- in the first one there's no offer, so the "cartell" wouldn't be showing. -->
                        </div>
                    </template>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I tried too a Jinja template, but I don't get a lot how it works. Any kind of help will be incredibly welcome. Thank you.

Comment: You are trying to send data from `frontend` to `backend` using `vue.js` and `fastapi` respectively, right?

Comment: No, it's from backend to frontend. I've got the data stored on fastapi. I want to render it on the web page.

Comment: Please, post your json example!

Comment: It's done. That's what I get from fastapi when I do a get request.

Comment: I didn't understand where to put which, I understood `urlimg` and `desc` clearly but other I don't know where to put which. Please make a template, add first json there and post it. I got other things absolutely right, but I didn't know which should be put where, so I haven't answered. Do that, and I will post answer and additionally I didn't understand this `v-if` things as well. `cartell` where is this?

Comment: I think it's this what you meant (it's the last snippet of code). If not, I'll correct it. Thank you. The v-if it's because I have 2 images, one that shows a "new offer" text and the other an "offer" text. I have to show one or none of them, that's why the v-if.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div class="row">
    <div v-for="prod in product" :data-id="prod.id" :key="prod.id" class="col-3 producte" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal1" on-click="reply_click($event)">
      <template>
        <div class="producte">
          <div class="imgdesc">
            <img :src="prod.urlimg" class="img-fluid"><br>
              {{ prod.desc }}
           </div>
           <img v-if="prod.oferta == 'new'" :src="prod.urlimg" class="cartell">
           <img v-if="prod.oferta == 'offer'" :src="prod.urlimg" class="cartell">
         </div>
       </template>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
            
<script>
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    product: [{
        "id": 1,
        "desc": "Kaweco sport capeless roller pen and pencil set in pouch white",
        "urlimg": "imgs/offer1.png",
        "preu": 22,
        "oferta": "no"
    },

    {
        "id": 2,
        "desc": "Hacoa masking tape holder",
        "urlimg": "imgs/offer2.png",
        "preu": 24,
        "oferta": "new"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "desc": "Hacoa black walnut business card holder",
        "urlimg": "imgs/offer3.png",
        "preu": 30,
        "oferta": "new"
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "desc": "Postalco legal envelope navy",
        "urlimg": "imgs/offer4.png",
        "preu": 15,
        "oferta": "offer"
    }]
  }
});
</script>
```

It should work for you perfectly! We have to use `:` to use vue data as an attribute in element and while using normally/as text we can do `{{ data }}` only.

Comment: No, we didn't use it. It's for a modal that I didn't do yet